# UWP SQLite-Net Extensions can't Insert Children

Tags: uwp, sqlite-net-extensions

I install SQLiteNetExtensions from nuget using Visual Studio 2015 in a UWP project. This is my model:

```
public class MovieItem 
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<EpisodeItem> Episodes { get; private set; }
}

public class EpisodeItem 
{
    private bool _selected;

    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Url { get; internal set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(MovieItem))]
    public string MovieUrl { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public MovieItem Movie { get; set; }
}
```

But when I run:

```
var movieItem = new MovieItem{
    Url='movie link',
    Episodes = new List<Episode>{
       Url='episode link'
    }
};
conn.InsertWithChildren(movieItem,true);
```

And open database file with SqliteBrowser. I get only MovieItem record without any Episode record. I have tried many ways but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `Episodes` setter to `public`:

```
public class MovieItem 
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<EpisodeItem> Episodes { get; set; }
}
```